# Django identify object through form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making a web page which has a list of objects, and each object has a button to delete it. I am making this with Django forms, but once I make the post I cannot identify from which object it came from. How do I do that?

This is my html code:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in item_list %}
        <li>
            <form name="{{ item.nombre }}" method="POST" action="/inventario/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" name="del_item" value="x">
                {{ item.nombre }}: {{ item.cantidad }}
            </form>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You can very well pass the `id` of the object under a hidden variable to the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you would want to include a hidden field with the item or object identifier:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="12345">
```

In python, you can get this out of the POST data.  As for deleting it from the list, I can't see your code to know how you store the list, but this might help:

```
ID = ... #get id from post data
for i in range(len(my_list_of_objects)):
    if my_list_of_objects[i] == ID:
        del(my_list_of_objects[i])  
        break
```

There is a specific reason I am not using `for obj in my_list_of_objects`.  Python is very strict about not changing the size of a list during iteration, so it is better to look at just the object indexes (offsets) and read/delete that way.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed